# Android Emulator causing Blue Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

[image]Whenever I am trying to run the Android Emulator (any Nougat, Oreo, or Kitkat) laptop throws a blue screen saying `STOP CODE IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL`.

My laptop will restart in 20 minutes or so and I can do everything else on my laptop and even run the Android app on my mobile using USB Debugging.

I tried reinstalling android studio and AVD manager several times but my issue is not getting resolved.

*PLEASE help!*

Laptop Configuration:

- Dell Inspiron 3576
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
- RAM: 8.00 GB (7.87 GB usable)
- System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Edition: Windows 10 Home Single Language
- Version: 20H2 (as of 01st April, 2021)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with NoxPlayer which is another android emulator, the stopcode was different but it was fixed when I created a new boot entry with Hyper-V Disabled.
Check this out:
https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2013/12/27/create-a-no-hyper-v-boot-option/
"Don't forget to change Windows8 to windows10 in your commands, That's just a name but it has to be meaningful :D"